# resetting mobile toggle button condition on screen change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile hamburger menu which animates 'open' and 'close' through css. If the screen enlarges >768px then the mobile menu `display:none` and a full screen menu is shown.

html

```
<button id="nav-icon" class="toggle-nav">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
</button>
```

jQuery

```
// Toggle x
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

However, If I have the mobile menu open and change the screen size to >768px the menu `display:none` (I have it reset to hide) but the toggle button remains 'open' so the functionality of the toggle button is in reverse (open animation closes it and vice-versa)

I want the button to reset if the screen scales back to to <768px(responsive)

Comment: Could you just toggle it at the same time you hide the menu when screen changes? Or `.trigger("click")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$(document).ready` function:

```
var mobileSize = 768;
var pastWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(this).width();
  if((width < mobileSize && pastWidth > mobileSize) || (width > mobileSize && pastWidth < mobileSize)) {
    $('#nav-icon').removeClass('open');
  }
  pastWidth = width;
});
```

Comment: Your code removes the css that is applied when clicked (the transform property doesn't work) . Is this a secondary code, to be included with it?

Comment: Do you have your code in a codepen or a jsfiddle so I can test it out?

Comment: My apologies, If I add this separately I managed to get it to work.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!